# Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException - JsonSchema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, jsonschema

I am trying to use `JsonSchema` to validate rows in an RDD, in order to filter out invalid rows.

Here is my code:

```
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.{JsonSchema, JsonSchemaFactory}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{JsonNode, ObjectMapper}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

def getJsonSchemaFactory: JsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault

def stringToJsonSchema(str: String): Try[JsonSchema] = {
  stringToJson(str).map(getJsonSchemaFactory.getJsonSchema(_))
}

def stringToJson(str: String): Try[JsonNode] = {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper
  Try({
    val json = mapper.readTree(str)
    json
  })
}

def validateJson(data: JsonNode, jsonSchema: JsonSchema): Boolean = {
  val report = jsonSchema.validateUnchecked(data, true)
  report.isSuccess
}

val schemaSource: String = ...
val jsonSchema: JsonSchema = stringToJsonSchema(schemaSource).get
val df = spark.read
  .textFile("path/to/data.json")
  .filter(str => {
    stringToJson(str)
      .map(validateJson(_, jsonSchema))
      .getOrElse(false)
  })
```

However, I'm getting an error because `JsonSchema` is not serializable:

```
Cause: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
[info]   Cause: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema
[info] Serialization stack:
[info]  - object not serializable (class: com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema, value: com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema@33d22225)
```

I have read these threads in search of a solution:

- [Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)
- [Spark - Task not serializable: How to work with complex map closures that call outside classes/objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050067/spark-task-not-serializable-how-to-work-with-complex-map-closures-that-call-o?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://github.com/samthebest/dump/blob/master/sams-scala-tutorial/serialization-exceptions-and-memory-leaks-no-ws.md
- https://www.placeiq.com/2017/11/how-to-solve-non-serializable-errors-when-instantiating-objects-in-spark-udfs/

And also some others.

As far as I understand - spark needs to serialize all the operations that I want to perform on the RDD, in order to send them to the worker nodes. But `JsonSchema` is not serializable, so it fails.

I have tried this solution:

```
  def genMapper[A, B](f: A => B): A => B = {
    val locker = com.twitter.chill.MeatLocker(f)
    x => locker.get.apply(x)
  }

  private class JsonSchemaValidator(jsonSchema: JsonSchema) extends (String => Boolean) {
    def apply(str: String): Boolean =
      stringToJson(str)
        .map(validateJson(_, jsonSchema))
        .getOrElse(false)
  }

val validator: String => Boolean = genMapper(new JsonSchemaValidator(jsonSchema))

df.filter(validator)
```

Because someone said it is supposed to be able to serialize anything. But I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread / executeTests 11s
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private volatile boolean jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.hasRun accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.misc" to unnamed module @7876b3b3
```

So I tried to solve it by adding some java options:

```
ThisBuild / javaOptions ++= Seq(
    "--add-opens", "java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens", "java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens", "java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED",
)
```

But this still throws an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.xml.internal.SecuritySupport$$Lambda$1262/0x0000000800c16840.writeReplace()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2475)
```

So I took a step back, and tried with `broadcast`:

```
val brdJsonSchema: Broadcast[JsonSchema] = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(jsonSchema)
df.filter(str => {
    stringToJson(str)
      .map(validateJson(_, brdJsonSchema.value))
      .getOrElse(false)
  })
```

But that gives a serialization error too.

Also tried it with `MeatLocker`:

```
val brdSerJsonSchema: Broadcast[MeatLocker[JsonSchema]] = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(MeatLocker(jsonSchema))
df.filter(str => {
    stringToJson(str)
      .map(validateJson(_, brdSerJsonSchema.value.get))
      .getOrElse(false)
  })
```

But then I'm getting the same error as the `genMapper` solution above, and adding the `javaOptions` does not help.

I did find a workaround, but I don't like it because it feels hacky:
I can parse the string source of the json schema inside the `filter` function:

```
val schemaSource: String = ...
df.filter(str => {
  val jsonSchema = stringToJsonSchema(schemaSource).get
  stringToJson(str)
    .map(validateJson(_, jsonSchema))
    .getOrElse(false)
})
```

But that means that I am parsing the `JsonSchema` for every row of the DF, and that's a waste of CPU and memory.

So instead I can use a cache-wrapper, which also feels hacky:

```
  class CacheWrapper[T] {
    private lazy val cache = mutable.Map.empty[String, T]

    def getCacheOrElse(cacheKey: String, getter: () => T): T = {
      cache.getOrElse(cacheKey, {
        cache.put(cacheKey, getter())
        cache(cacheKey)
      })
    }
  }

val schemaSource: String = ...
@transient lazy val jsonSchemaCache: CacheWrapper[JsonSchema] = new CacheWrapper[JsonSchema]
df.filter(str => {
  val jsonSchema = jsonSchemaCache.getOrElse(schemaSource.hashCode.toString, () => stringToJsonSchema(schemaSource).get)
  stringToJson(str)
    .map(validateJson(_, jsonSchema))
    .getOrElse(false)
})
```

This will have the effect of parsing the `JsonSchema` only once (when we reach the first row). All the other rows will get it from the cache.

But again - this feels hacky.

Is there another way to do this?

All I want is a way to pass the `schemaSource` string to all the spark worker nodes, have each worker parse it into a `JsonSchema` only once, and then use that `JsonSchema` object to filter the DF. That sounds to me like it should be easy, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Just a side note, the com.github.fge JSON schema implementation is no longer maintained and quite old. Maybe you want to consider selecting a different Java validator from here https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators ?

Comment: @Clemens thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: Update - I switched to using `com.networknt.json-schema-validator` which seems to be more modern, and it has the exact same serialization problems, and the solution below works for it too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so a coworker helped me find a solution.

Sources:

- https://nathankleyn.com/2017/12/29/using-transient-and-lazy-vals-to-avoid-spark-serialisation-issues/
- https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/serialization-issues-part-2/read#serializable_factory_wrapper

Code:

```
private class JsonSchemaValidator(schemaSource: String) extends (String => Boolean) with Serializable {
    @transient lazy val jsonSchema: JsonSchema = JsonSchemaDFParser.stringToJsonSchema(schemaSource).get

    def apply(str: String): Boolean = 
      stringToJson(str)
        .map(validateJson(_, jsonSchema))
        .getOrElse(false)
  }

val validator: String => Boolean = new JsonSchemaValidator(schemaSource)

df.filter(validator)
```

`@transient` has the effect of excluding the item from the object when it is serialised.
`lazy` means the field will be constructed again when first accessed on each of the executors.

The wrapping class has to extend Serializable for this to work.

NOTE: This solution works. It does what I want it to do. BUT - it's still strange to me that it had to be so hard to do this. I might be missing some feature of Spark, but the fact I needed to find this very special syntax to do such a simple thing feels to me like a design flaw.