# java+spark: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I'm new to spark, and was trying to run the example JavaSparkPi.java, it runs well, but because i have to use this in another java s I copy all things from main to a method in the class and try to call the method in main, it saids

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted: Task not serializable:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException

the code looks like this:

```
public class JavaSparkPi {

public void cal(){
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "JavaLogQuery");
    int slices = 2;
    int n = 100000 * slices;

    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l.add(i);
    }

    JavaRDD<Integer> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(l, slices);

    System.out.println("count is: "+ dataSet.count());
    dataSet.foreach(new VoidFunction<Integer>(){
        public void call(Integer i){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    });

    int count = dataSet.map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer integer) throws Exception {
            double x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            double y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            return (x * x + y * y < 1) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }).reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer integer, Integer integer2) throws Exception {
            return integer + integer2;
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JavaSparkPi myClass = new JavaSparkPi();
    myClass.cal();
}
}
```

anyone have idea on this? thanks!

Comment: You omitted the most important line in the error. What class is not Serializable?

Comment: @SeanOwen Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mycompany.sparkproject2.JavaSparkPi is this the one?

Comment: I think your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/scala-spark-task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexceptionon-when/22594142#22594142

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The nested functions hold a reference to the containing object (`JavaSparkPi`). So this object will get serialized. For this to work, it needs to be serializable. Simple to do:

```
public class JavaSparkPi implements Serializable {
  ...
```

Comment: This is right, or, make the anonymous classes inner static classes, if you can't or don't want to make the outer class static. This is more hassle code-wise though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818001/understanding-spark-serialization/40818002?sfb=2#40818002   an overview for understanding spark serialization

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that when you create an Anonymous Class in java it is passed a reference of the enclosing class.
This can be fixed in many ways

### Declare the enclosing class Serializable

This works in your case but will fall flat in case your enclosing class has some field that is not serializable. I would also say that serializing the parent class is a total waste.

### Create the Closure in a static function

Creating the closure by invoking some static function doesn't pass the reference to the closure and hence no need to make serializable this way.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you have multiple physical CPUs in your local or cluster and spark engine try to send this function to multiple CPUs over network.
Your function

```
 dataSet.foreach(new VoidFunction<Integer>(){
        public void call(Integer i){
            ***System.out.println(i);***
        }
    });
```

uses println() which is not serialize. So the exception thrown by Spark Engine.
The  solution is you can use below:

```
dataSet.collect().forEach(new VoidFunction<Integer>(){
       public void call(Integer i){
         System.out.println(i);
    }
});
```