# Unable to print Hana Data from Spark shell

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql

With below code I am trying to connect to HANA from spark-shell and bring the data from a particular table:

```
    spark-submit --properties-file /users/xxx/spark-defaults.conf
    ./spark-shell --properties-file /users/xxx/spark-defaults.conf
    val sparksqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) 
    val driver ="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver"
    val url ="jdbc:sap://yyyyyy:12345"
    val database= "STAGING"
    val username  = "uuuuu"
    val password = "zzzzzz"
    val table_view = "STAGING.Tablename"
    val jdbcDF = sparksqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver",driver).option("url",url).option("databaseName", database).option("user", username).option("password",password).option("dbtable", table_view).option("partitionColumn","INSTANCE_ID").option("lowerBound","7418403").option("upperBound","987026473").option("numPartitions","5").load()
    jdbcDF.cache
    jdbcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("TESTING_hanaCopy")
    val results = sparksqlContext.sql("select * from TESTING_hanaCopy")
    val resultsCounts = sparksqlContext.sql("select count(*) from TESTING_hanaCopy")
    val countsval=results.count()
    resultsCounts.show()
```

The error is as below:

> scala> resultsCounts.show()
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host
>   Serialization stack:
>           - object not serializable (class: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host, value: yyyyyy:12345)
>           - writeObject data (class: java.util.ArrayList)
>           - object (class java.util.ArrayList, [yyyyyy:12345])
>           - writeObject data (class: java.util.Hashtable)
>           - object (class java.util.Properties, {databasename=STAGING, dburl=jdbc:sap://yyyyyy:12345, user=uuuuu, password=zzzzzz, hostlist=[yyyyyy:12345]})
>           - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions, name: asConnectionProperties, type: class java.util.Properties)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions@7cd755a1)
>           - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1, name: options$1, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions)

I tried to understand the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046744/javaspark-org-apache-spark-sparkexception-job-aborted-task-not-serializable) and [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html) but could not understand what to change in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Note section from this [Blog](http://www.saphanacentral.com/2016/09/calling-hana-views-from-apache-spark.html) post resolved the issue:

> Note: I’ve tested Spark using the recent SPS12 version of the Hana JDBC Driver (ngdbc.jar)  against a SPS10 & SPS12 system and both seem ed to work fine.  Older versions of the driver give the following error in Spark: ‘ org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host’