# parsing JSON into classes with Option[T] arg types in spark-shell with Scala

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I'm having trouble parsing JSON with json4s.jackson in spark-shell.  The same thing works fine in sbt repl.

I wonder if there's a workaround for the version of Spark I'm using.

- spark-shell v1.6, scala v2.10.5
- sbt repl scala v 2.11.8

.

The following example demonstrates the problem.

- sbt repl works as expected for all examples.
- spark-shell chokes and gives an error for `val c`.  What's weird is that it seems to choke on `Option[Int]` or `Option[Double]` but it works fine for `Option[A]` where A is a class.

.

```
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.{render,compact,pretty}

import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.{JValue, JObject} 

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats


class A(val a: Int, val aa: Int)
class B(val b: Int, val optA: Option[A]=None)
class C(val b: Int, val bb: Option[Int]=None)

val jb_optA_nested: JObject     = ("b" -> 5) ~ ("optA" -> ("a" -> 999) ~ ("aa" -> 1000))
val jb_optA_not_nested: JObject = ("b" -> 5) ~ ("a" -> 999) ~ ("aa" -> 1000)
val jb_optA_none: JObject       = ("b" -> 5)
val jc: JObject                 = ("b" -> 5) ~ ("bb" -> 100)


val b_nested     = jb_optA_nested.extract[B]      // works as expected in both (optA=Some(A(999,1000)))
val b_not_nested = jb_optA_not_nested.extract[B]  // works as expected in both (optA=None)
val b_none       = jb_optA_none.extract[B]        // works as expected in both (optA=None)
val c            = jc.extract[C]                  // error in spark-shell; works fine in sbt repl
```

The error generated is:  `org.json4s.package$MappingException: Can't find constructor for C`

The only real difference I can find (other than scala versions) is that in spark-shell...  it chokes on Option[native types] and seems to work on Option[user-defined classes].  But maybe that's coincidence.

In posts like this...  [JSON4s can't find constructor w/spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666487/json4s-cant-find-constructor-w-spark)  I see comments where people suggest the class structure doesn't match the JSON...  but to me, `class C` and `val jc` look identical.

Also of note...  this error persists when I harden class defs and functions in a .JAR and import defs into spark-shell from the jar instead of defining in the repl.  sometimes that's relevant for spark 1.6, but doesn't seem to be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
class C(val b: Int, val bb: Option[java.lang.Integer]=None)
```

I've had issues with the Scala `Int` before with Json4s - although I can't recall exactly what it was.

Also doing a `case class` is worthwhile with the `Int` - any reason you prefer a regular `class`? I don't see any `var`s.

Comment: Thank you!  This solves it.  note...  not using case classes because my real code doesn't use case classes...  try to strip it down for stackoverflow to minimum toy example that demonstrates the problem, but keep what I can the same.