# Scala variable resets after for-each loop / string gets truncated

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I am doing a Spark project. In the following code, I have a string which I use to collect my results in order to write to a file later on (I know this is not the correct way, I am just checking what is inside a `Tuple3` returned by a method). The string gets truncated after a for each loop. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
val newLine = sys.props("line.separator") // also tried "\n". I am using OS X.

var str = s"*** ${newLine}"

for (tuple3 <- ArrayOfTuple3s) {
  for (list <- tuple3._3) {
    for (strItem <- list) {
      str += s"${strItem}, "
    }
    str += s"${newLine}"
  }
  str += s"${newLine}"
  println(tempStr)
}

print("str=" + str)
```

The first `println` method call prints the correct value of the string (the concatenated result), but when the loop ends, the value of `str` is `***` (the same value assigned to it before the first loop).

**Edit:** I replaced the `str` immutable `String` object with a `StringBuilder`, but no change in the result:

```
val newLine: String = sys.props("line.separator")

var str1: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(15000)

for (tuple3 <- ArrayOfTuple3s) {
  for (list <- tuple3._3) {
    for (str <- list) {
      str1.append(s"${str}, ")
    }
    str1.append(s"${newLine}")
  }
  str1.append(s"${newLine}")
  println(str1.toString())
}

print("resulting str1=" + str1.toString())
```

**Edit 2:** I mapped the RDD to take the Tuple3's third field directly. This field itself is an RDD of Arrays of Lists. I changed the code accordingly, but I am still getting the same result (the resulting string is empty, although inside the for loop it is not).

```
val rddOfArraysOfLists = getArrayOfTuple3s(mainRdd).map(_._3)

for (arrayOfLists <- rddOfArraysOfLists) {
  for (list <- arrayOfLists) {
    for (field <- list) {
      str1.append(s"${field}, ")
    }
    str1.append(" -- ")
  }
  str1.append(s"${newLine}")
  println(str1.toString())
}
```

**Edit 4:** I think the problem is not with strings at all. There seems to be a problem with all types of variables.

```
var count = 0

for (arrayOfLists <- myArray) {
  count = arrayOfLists.last(3).toInt
  println(s"count=$count")
}

println(s"count=$count")
```

The value is non-zero inside the loop, but it is 0 outside the loop. Any idea?

**Edit 5:** I cannot publish the whole code (due to confidentiality restrictions), but here is the major part of it. If it matters, I am running Spark on my local machine in Intellij Idea (for debugging).

```
System.setProperty("spark.cores.max", "8")
System.setProperty("spark.executor.memory", "15g")    
val sc = new SparkContext("local", getClass.getName)            
val samReg = sc.objectFile[Sample](sampleLocation, 200).distinct

val samples = samReg.filter(f => f.uuid == "dce03545e8034242").sortBy(_.time).cache()

val top3Samples = samples.take(3)
for (sample <- top3Samples) {
  print("sample: ")
  println(s"uuid=${sample.uuid}, time=${sample.time}, model=${sample.model}")
}

val firstTimeStamp = samples.first.time
val targetTime = firstTimeStamp + 2592000 // + 1 month in seconds (samples during the first month)

val rddOfArrayOfSamples = getCountsRdd(samples.filter(_.time <= targetTime)).map(_._1).cache()
// Due to confidentiality matters, I cannot reveal the code, 
// but here is a description:
// I have an array of samples. Each sample has a few String fields 
// and is represented by a List[String]
// The above RDD is of the type RDD[Array[List[String]]]. 
// It contains only a single array of samples
// (because I passed a filtered set of samples to the function), 
// but it may contain more.
// The fourth field of each sample (list) is an increasing number (count)

println(s"number of arrays in the RDD: ${rddOfArrayOfSamples.count()}")

var maxCount = 0
for (arrayOfLists <- rddOfArrayOfSamples) {
  println(s"Last item of the array (a list)=${arrayOfLists.last}")
  maxCount = arrayOfLists.last(3).toInt
  println(s"maxCount=${maxCount}")
}
println(s"maxCount=${maxCount}")
```

The output:

sample: uuid=dce03545e8034242, time=1360037324, model=Nexus 4

sample: uuid=dce03545e8034242, time=1360037424, model=Nexus 4

sample: uuid=dce03545e8034242, time=1360037544, model=Nexus 4

number of arrays in the RDD: 1

Last item of the array (a list)=List(dce03545e8034242, Nexus 4, 1362628767, 32, 2089, 0.97, 0.15999999999999992, 0)

maxCount=32

maxCount=0

Comment: The first cannot be the code you actually run (as it mentions tempStr in the println). Can you post a complete example? Most likely you have two things named str1.

Comment: Also, I think your loops could be replaced with `ArrayOfTuples..map(t => t._3.mkString("", ", ", newLine)).mkString("", newLine, "")`

Comment: Thank you @Paul. The naming is correct in my main code, I did a partial rename when I was creating this post (to make the name shorter and less distractive), but in my main code, all of the names are identical (tempStr).

Comment: Regarding the mkstring, I think I cannot use it, because my RDD is not flat. See the code in my last edit. The third object of the tuple itself is an RDD **(list) of arrays of lists**.

Comment: @Paul, please see my last edit.

Comment: There's something odd going on but it's not easy to workout because of the lack of info about types. Can you please post a *complete* example?

Comment: @Paul please see the new edit.

Comment: What happens if you println just the variable (i.e. without string interpolation)?

Comment: nothing, the same result (zero value outside the loop).

Comment: It would really help if you could produce a runnable example. I understand the confidentiality point, but if we can't run something to reproduce your problem it's really difficult to make progress.

Comment: So I don't really know the architecture of Spark, but what  I think is happening is: in general the `map` (that the `for` translates into) can execute in multiple nodes. So there can't really be one `maxCount` that's shared by all executions of the body of the for/map. So the `maxCount` you're modifying isn't the same `maxCount` you're declaring.  Imagine if there were many lines in your rddOfArrayOfSamples, and the map/for was distributed across nodes, and for every row, a single/shared maxCount was updated - it would be fairly random which one got updated.

Comment: That seems to be the only plausible explanation. If a for-each loop translates to a map, then that might be true, because Spark's map happens on the worker nodes, not on the master node. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I added it as an answer, with a bit more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uprating my explanation in a comment to an answer:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22596875/21755) to a somewhat-related question:

> Not to get into too many details, but when you run different
>   transformations on a RDD (map, flatMap, filter and others), your
>   transformation code (closure) is:
>
> serialized on the driver node,
>   shipped to the appropriate nodes in the cluster,
>   deserialized,
>   and finally executed on the nodes

The `for` in your code is just syntactic sugar for a `map`.

Because of this, the `maxCount` that each execution updates is not the same `maxCount` in your invoking program. That one never changes.

The lesson here is don't use closures (blocks) that update vars outside the block

Comment: I am wondering why this is happening even when I am running Spark on a single node (my local machine). Probably even when you run Spark on a single machine, there are two distinct threads/processes: a master process and a worker process, and probably they use different segments of the memory and they don't share memory?

Comment: By the way, then what approach do you suggest for handling this problem?

Comment: Of course one approach (or more accurately, a hack) that I used was to write the value I am fetching into a file, inside the closure/block.

Comment: If your use case is to calculate the max, `map` the RDD to just the counts, then use `reduce`. Or call `.max()`, passing in an appropriate Ordering.

Comment: Wonderful! I also found this useful: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#shared-variables

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post a complete example I had to arbitrate some portion of the code.

For your 4th edit I made:

```
val myArray = Array(
  List(List(0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  List(List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(1, 1, 1, 1)),
  List(List(2, 2, 2, 2), List(2, 2, 2, 2), List(2, 2, 2, 2))
)
```

Running in the REPL:

```
var count = 0

for (arrayOfLists <- myArray) {
  count = arrayOfLists.last(3).toInt
  println(s"count=$count")
}

println(s"count=$count")
```

I get:

```
scala> for (arrayOfLists <- myArray) {
     |   count = arrayOfLists.last(3).toInt
     |   println(s"count=$count")
     | }
count=0
count=1
count=2

scala> println(s"count=$count")
count=2
```

The value is non-zero inside the loop **and** non-zero outside the loop.

If you please post a *complete* example, maybe we can help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have the same problem. Please see my last edit.