# Spark Task Serialization error during broadcast with in for loop

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, broadcast

I am trying to broadcast a variable within a for loop in spark. During this process, spark is throwing task not serialize-able error. If the same variable is broadcasted out of the for loop, there is no error. Below is code snippet that throws error. Any help is appreciated.

```
var Final = computedRDD.filter(x => x.Id == uniqueKey(0))

for (partId <- uniqueKey) {
      val FinalBroadcast = sc.broadcast(Final.collect)
      val computeNew = computedRDD.filter(x => x.partId == partId).repartition(executors).mapPartitions(performFinalPass(FinalBroadcast))
      computeNew.collect.forall(x => Final.add(x))
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)

Comment: Can you share the code of performFinalPass method?