# Scala, Play2.4, Spark: Task Not Serializable due to SparkConf object

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, playframework-2.4

I'm using Spark with Scala and Play2.4. First of all, I saw this thread:
[Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)

I'm ok with the fact that if we pass a method to Spark, it tries to serialize the whole class.

My code, it will be clearer:

```
class GPSSparkServiceImpl @Inject() (val stepService: StepDbService, val coordinateService: CoordinateService) extends GPSSparkService with Serializable{

  /**
   * Spark config
   * Set Master node and AppName
   */
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Editus GPS").setMaster("local[2]")

  /**
   * Initialize Spark Context
   */
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  override def execute() = {
    val logData = sc.textFile("file://C://work/csv/gps.csv").cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s".format(numAs))
  }

  override def generateUserToStep(): Unit = {
    val futureSteps = stepService.findAll()
    futureSteps onSuccess{
      case steps =>
        val data = sc.textFile("file://C://work/csv/gps.csv").cache()
        val result = data.flatMap(line => steps.map(step => (line, step))).filter { tuple =>
          coordinateService.checkProximity(
            coordinateService.coordinateToDistanceInMeters(
              tuple._1.split(";")(1).toDouble, tuple._1.split(";")(2).toDouble, tuple._2.gpsCoordinate.latitude, tuple._2.gpsCoordinate.longitude
            ), tuple._2
          )
        }.count()
        println("result: " + result + " for " + steps.length + " steps")
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I use 2 methods in spark: `checkProximity` and `CoordinateToDistanceInMeters` from `CoordinateService` which will be injected as `CoordinateServiceImpl` and this class is serializable. All objects in the class are serializable.

CoordinateServiceImpl:

```
class CoordinateServiceImpl @Inject() (val config: Configuration) extends CoordinateService with Serializable{

  override def coordinateToDistanceInMeters(lat1: Double, lng1: Double, lat2: Double, lng2: Double): Double = {
    val earthRadius: Double = 6371000
    val dLat: Double = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1)
    val dLng: Double = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1)
    val a: Double = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
      Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2)
    val c: Double = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))
    earthRadius * c
  }

  override def checkProximity(distance: Double, step: Step): Boolean =
    distance < step.acceptableProximity
}
```

Why am I facing SparkConf not serializable, which is in the actual class ? I'm not even using any method of it. Maybe I'm missing something ....

The stacktrace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable                                                                
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)                         
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)                                      
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)                                               
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:303)                                                             
        at services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl$$anonfun$generateUserToStep$1.applyOrElse(GPSSparkServiceImpl.scala:
41)                                                                                                                   
        at services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl$$anonfun$generateUserToStep$1.applyOrElse(GPSSparkServiceImpl.scala:
38)                                                                                                                   
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(Future.scala:117)                                       
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(Future.scala:115)                                       
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)                                               
        at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)        
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)                                       
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)                    
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)                           
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)                                   
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)                          
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf                                               
Serialization stack:                                                                                                  
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkConf, value: org.apache.spark.SparkConf@1b0321ae)     
        - field (class: services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl, name: conf, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkConf)   
        - object (class services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl, services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl@458c4049)      
        - field (class: services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl$$anonfun$generateUserToStep$1, name: $outer, type: clas
s services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl)                                                                             
        - object (class services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl$$anonfun$generateUserToStep$1, <function1>)            
        - field (class: services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl$$anonfun$generateUserToStep$1$$anonfun$3, name: $outer,
 type: class services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl$$anonfun$generateUserToStep$1)                                    
        - object (class services.gps.spark.GPSSparkServiceImpl$$anonfun$generateUserToStep$1$$anonfun$3, <function1>) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:38)        
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)                   
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)                      
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)                         


 ... 14 more
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in DI, but IMO since you are injecting `coordinateService` into `GPSSparkServiceImpl` and using it in the closure you have to serialize whole `GPSSparkServiceImpl`, some parts of which are not serializable (namely `conf`). Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use an object instead of an injected class, it works perfectly.

```
object GpsUtils{
  def coordinateToDistanceInMeters(lat1: Double, lng1: Double, lat2: Double, lng2: Double): Double = {
    val earthRadius: Double = 6371000
    val dLat: Double = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1)
    val dLng: Double = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1)
    val a: Double = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
      Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2)
    val c: Double = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))
    earthRadius * c
  }

  def checkProximity(distance: Double, step: Step): Boolean =
    distance < step.acceptableProximity
}
```