# spark java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm try to implement to check exist record by received message from kafka in spark by spark streaming, now when i run RunReadLogByKafka object, there is a NotSerializableException for SparkContext was throwed, i google it, but i still don't know how to fix it, Could anyone suggest me how to rewrite it? thanks in advance.

```
package com.test.spark.hbase

import java.sql.{DriverManager, PreparedStatement, Connection}
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import com.powercn.spark.LogRow
import com.powercn.spark.SparkReadHBaseTest.{SensorStatsRow, SensorRow}
import kafka.serializer.{DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{TableName, HBaseConfiguration}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ConnectionFactory, Result, Put}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.{TableInputFormat, TableOutputFormat}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, Row}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

case class LogRow(rowkey: String, content: String)

object LogRow {
  def parseLogRow(result: Result): LogRow = {
    val rowkey = Bytes.toString(result.getRow())
    val p0 = rowkey
    val p1 = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("content")))
    LogRow(p0, p1)
  }
}

 class ReadLogByKafka(sct:SparkContext) extends Serializable {

   implicit def func(records: String) {
    @transient val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "log")
    @transient val sc = sct
    @transient val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    try {
      //query info table
      val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
        classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
        classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
      println(hBaseRDD.count())
      // transform (ImmutableBytesWritable, Result) tuples into an RDD of Results
      val resultRDD = hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2)
      println(resultRDD.count())
      val logRDD = resultRDD.map(LogRow.parseLogRow)
      val logDF = logRDD.toDF()
      logDF.printSchema()
      logDF.show()
      // register the DataFrame as a temp table
      logDF.registerTempTable("LogRow")
      val logAdviseDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rowkey, content as content FROM LogRow ")
      logAdviseDF.printSchema()
      logAdviseDF.take(5).foreach(println)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {

    }
  }

}

package com.test.spark.hbase

import kafka.serializer.{DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.{TableInputFormat, TableOutputFormat}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}


object RunReadLogByKafka extends Serializable {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val broker = "192.168.13.111:9092"
    val topic = "log"

    @transient val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("RunReadLogByKafka")
    @transient val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    @transient val sc = streamingContext.sparkContext

    val kafkaConf = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> broker,
      "group.id" -> "group1",
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "3000",
      "kafka.auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")

    // Define which topics to read from
    val topics = Set(topic)

    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](
      streamingContext, kafkaConf, topics).map(_._2)

    messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val readLogByKafka =new ReadLogByKafka(sc)
      //parse every message, it will throw NotSerializableException
      rdd.foreach(readLogByKafka.func)
    })

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }


}

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:889)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:888)
    at com.test.spark.hbase.RunReadLogByKafka$$anonfun$main$1.apply(RunReadLogByKafka.scala:38)
    at com.test.spark.hbase.RunReadLogByKafka$$anonfun$main$1.apply(RunReadLogByKafka.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:207)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@5207878f)
    - field (class: com.test.spark.hbase.ReadLogByKafka, name: sct, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class com.test.spark.hbase.ReadLogByKafka, com.test.spark.hbase.ReadLogByKafka@60212100)
    - field (class: com.test.spark.hbase.RunReadLogByKafka$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, name: readLogByKafka$1, type: class com.test.spark.hbase.ReadLogByKafka)
    - object (class com.test.spark.hbase.RunReadLogByKafka$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)

Comment: I have read this link, but i don't know how to rewirte my code, i try to add @transient  for sparkContext, but it still throw the NotSerializableException .

Comment: try enabling `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` and then create the `SparkContext` in `foreach` or in `ReadLogByKafka`. **NOTE** This is not recommend approach but in some extreme you may need it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes,  if elable `allowMultipleContexts` ,the SparkContext can be called in foreach  in ReadLogByKafka, i don't know if it can be implemented use only one context.

Answer (score 0):

Object you get as an argument in `foreachRDD` is a standard Spark RDD so you have to obey exactly the same rules as usual including no nested actions or transformations and no access to the `SparkContext`. It is not exactly clear what you try to achieve (It doesn't look like `ReadLogByKafka.func` is doing anything useful) but I am guess you're looking for some kind of `join`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,  in fact, i want to execute query hbase by received message via spark hive in here,so i want to get the 'sparkContext' in 'foreach' in 'ReadLogByKafka.func'

Comment: You can try directly but not using Spark tools.