# Generic parser class `Task not serializable`

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to construct class which receives a parser as an argument and uses this parser on each line. Below is a minimal example that you can paste into `spark-shell`.

```
import scala.util.{Success,Failure,Try}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Reader[T : ClassTag](makeParser: () => (String => Try[T])) {

  def read(): Seq[T] = {

    val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("1","2","oops","4")) mapPartitions { lines =>

      // Since making a parser can be expensive, we want to make only one per partition.
      val parser: String => Try[T] = makeParser()

      lines flatMap { line =>
        parser(line) match {
          case Success(record) => Some(record)
          case Failure(_) => None
        }
      }
    }

    rdd.collect()
  }
}

class IntParser extends (String => Try[Int]) with Serializable {
  // There could be an expensive setup operation here...
  def apply(s: String): Try[Int] = Try { s.toInt }
}
```

However, when I try to run something like `new Reader(() => new IntParser).read()` (which type-checks just fine) I get the dreaded `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` error relating to closures.

Why is there an error and is there a way to re-engineer the above to avoid this (while keeping `Reader` generic)?

Comment: Strange. The function is only closing over `makeParser`, but `() => new IntParser` should be serializable. What happens if you replace passing `makeParser` with `parser` as argument?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov If I just make `parser` the argument to `Reader[T]` I still get the same message (slightly different trace, but still closure related)

Comment: @Alec - Quick fix move the line val parser: String => Try[T] = makeParser() before the val rdd = ..

Comment: @Knight71 doesn't that mean that I no longer have one parser per partition though? Thanks though, that gives me something to ponder. Maybe with lazy values...

Comment: you will have one parser per rdd and this parser will be distributed across executors.

Comment: @Knight71 I'm a bit new to Spark. Do executors and nodes have a one-to-one relationship (per rdd, of course)?

Comment: need not necessarily the executors and nodes (workers). In general executors are your app that will be running inside your worker. If you have N app and M workers . Then your apps will be distributed equally among the workers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `makeParser` is variable to `class Reader` and since you are using it inside rdd transformations spark will try to serialize the entire class Reader which is not serializable. So you will get task not serializable exception.

Adding Serializable to the class Reader will work with your code. But that is not a good practice since it will serialize entire class variables which might not be needed.

In general you could use the functions instead of method to avoid serialization issues. Because in scala functions are actually objects and it will be serialized.

Refer to this answer : 
[Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou?rq=1)

Comment: Alternate fixes: 

1. make `makeParser` an argument of `read`, not of `Reader`.
2. Change `read` to store the `makeParser` function in a local variable: `val makeParser0 = makeParser; ... val parser: String => Try[T] = makeParser0() ...`.

Comment: Ahhh! That first paragraph explains it - everything makes sense now. @AlexeyRomanov I will likely end up doing just that!