# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable. How to run a method in map{}

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I try to call a method on a value. But get an error. My method.

```
processDate(p(2))
```

The values look somewhat like **20160125204123**

This is my class.

```
class ScalaJob(sc: SparkContext) {
  def run(filePath: String) : RDD[(String, String, String)] = {
    //pass the file
    val file = sc.textFile(filePath);
    //find values in every raw
    val values = file.map{
      dataRaw =>
      val p = dataRaw.split("[|]",-1)
      (p(1), processDate(p(2)), p(32))
    }
```

My method should return a string

```
def processDate(s: String) : String = {
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: processDate function is part of ScalaJob ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code used inside `RDD.map` in this case `file.map` will be serialized and shipped to executors. So for this to happen, the code should be serializable. In this case you have used the method `processDate` which is defined elsewhere. Make sure the class in which the method is defined is serializable. Note: you need to make the entire dependency chain serializable. One quick option is bind `processDate` to a val as a function and use it inside `RDD`. Or define the method in an object. Example:

```
class ScalaJob(sc: SparkContext) {
  def run(filePath: String): RDD[(String, String, String)] = {
    //pass the file
    val file = sc.textFile(filePath);
   //find values in every raw
    val process = processDate _
    val values = file.map {
      dataRaw =>
        val p = dataRaw.split("[|]", -1)
        (p(1), process(p(2)), p(32))
    }
  }
}
```

See [Spark Task Not Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou) for more details

Comment: I gave a sample. I have followed this approach in my development and it will work. The concept is simple. When you use a method inside `map`, it gets closed over and serialized. In order for the serialization to succeed, the complete dependency chain should be serialized. Instead when you bind the method to a function outside of `map`, a method local immutable copy is created which will not have serialization issues.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming because  the  `sc: SparkContext` which is *Non serializable by nature*. Spark will try to send entire ScalaJob for [closure](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka) which includes `sc`. Thats where the problem comes.The fix is make the `sc @transient`

Your class defination should be like this

```
class ScalaJob(@transient sc: SparkContext ) extends Serializable { }
```