# Using Class Methods in Spark RDD Operations Returns Task not serializable Exception

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

Suppose I have the following class in Spark Scala:

```
class SparkComputation(i: Int, j: Int) {
  def something(x: Int, y: Int) = (x + y) * i

  def processRDD(data: RDD[Int]) = {
    val j = this.j
    val something = this.something _
    data.map(something(_, j))
  }
}
```

I get the `Task not serializable Exception` when I run the following code:

```
val s = new SparkComputation(2, 5)
val data = sc.parallelize(0 to 100)
val res = s.processRDD(data).collect
```

I'm assuming that the exception occurs because Spark is trying to serialize the SparkComputation instance. To prevent this from happening, I have stored the class members I'm using in the RDD operation in local variables (`j` and `something`). However, Spark still tries to serialize `SparkComputation` object because of the method. Is there anyway to pass the class method to `map` without forcing Spark to serializing the whole `SparkComputation` class? I know the following code works without any problem:

```
def processRDD(data: RDD[Int]) = {
    val j = this.j
    val i = this.i
    data.map(x => (x + j) * i)
  }
```

So, the class members that store values are not causing the problem. The problem is with the function.
I have also tried the following approach with no luck:

```
class SparkComputation(i: Int, j: Int) {
  def processRDD(data: RDD[Int]) = {
    val j = this.j
    val i = this.i
    def something(x: Int, y: Int) = (x + y) * i
    data.map(something(_, j))
  }
}
```

Comment: This is famous error occurs due to class declaration... change it to object or extend serializable  then it should work.

Comment: @RamPrasadG There is no way to store the methods in local values like I do with other members (`i` and `j` in this example)?

Comment: have a  look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Make the class serializable:

```
class SparkComputation(i: Int, j: Int) extends Serializable {
  def something(x: Int, y: Int) = (x + y) * i

  def processRDD(data: RDD[Int]) = {
    val j = this.j
    val something = this.something _
    data.map(something(_, j))
  }
}
```