# how to test function in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

let's say I have a spark rdd and need to process it.

```
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(index, iter)=>
  def someFunc(){}
  def anotherFunc(){}

  val x = someFunc(iter)
  val y = anotherFunc(index, iter, x)
  x zip y
}
```

I define the someFunc and anotherFunc inside the mapParititions because I don't want to define them in the driver and then serialize them to the worker. it works, but I can not test it because it's a nested function. how to test this? need to write test case for those functions. currently I can serialize it. but what if the function is not serializable and can not send from driver to worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole lambda will be serialized, so also inner functions ;)

You can:

- create helper object to hold those functions and create test for this object
- create static nested class

Remember to:

1. mark all non-serializable fields with `@transient`
2. mark your object/class with `implements Serializable`

You can create also an integration test, which will create Spark Context and run calculations in local mode

More information can be found i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou?rq=1)