# Why my Spark program runs fine within IntelliJ but throws "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable" after being submitted?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

My code looks like this (sorry, there's a reason I can't show the full code):

```
public class MyClass {

    final A _field1; // Non-serializable object
    final B _field2; // Non-serializable object

    public void doSomething() {
        myJavaDStream...
                     .mapToPair(t -> {
                         // Do some stuff with _field1 and _field2
                     })
                     .reduceByKey((b1, b2) -> {
                         // Do other stuff with _field1 and _field2
                     })
                     ...
    }
}

public static void main() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.doSomething();
}
```

Within IntelliJ, everything works just fine. But after building and submitting the jar file with `spark-submit`, it throws `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. The stack trace points to the lambda in `mapToPair`.

My questions are: What's the difference between running within IDE and in stand-alone mode? How can I make it work properly?

Comment: Your class includes a couple of non-serializable objects, so per definition your class is _not_ serializable. When you run inside IntelliJ, everything is run locally to IntelliJ, so it doesn't have to actually distribute the class. When running in stand-alone mode it _will_ have to distribute (and hence serialize) the class, which is why you see the error in stand-alone mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I just figured out the solution. For non-serializable classes, esp. from 3rd party lib, you can [wrap them with Twitter Chill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769360/3123541), which comes with Spark, like so:

```
import com.twitter.chill.MeatLocker;

public class MyClass {

    final MeatLocker<A> _field1; // Non-serializable object

    public void doSomething() {
        myJavaDStream...
                     .map(t -> {
                         // call _field1.get() instead of _field1 to unwrap the value
                     })
    }
}
```