# spark object not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there any idea on why the whole object B need to be serialized?

```
object A{

  def main(args:Array[String])= {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd=sc.makeRDD(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
    val b=new B
    b.add(rdd)
  }
}
class B {

  val s="456"
  def add=(rdd:RDD[Int])=>{
    rdd.map(e=>e+" "+s).foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Exception about "object not serializable":

```
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: B, value: B@1fde4f40)
- field (class: B$$anonfun$add$1, name: $outer, type: class B)
- object (class B$$anonfun$add$1, <function1>)
- field (class: B$$anonfun$add$1$$anonfun$apply$1, name: $outer, type: class B$$anonfun$add$1)
- object (class B$$anonfun$add$1$$anonfun$apply$1, <function1>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See at the linked [Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou). What your syntax

```
def add=(rdd:RDD[Int])=>{
  rdd.map(e=>e+" "+s).foreach(println)
}
```

really means is

```
def addReal(): RDD[Int] => Unit = (rdd: RDD[Int]) => {
  val rddFunc: Int => String = e => e + " " + s
  rdd.map(rddFunc).foreach(println)
}
```

So now `rddFunc` [captures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) `s` from the context of its containing object `B` and this is done by actually capturing the whole object `B` which is not serializable.

So besides options listed in the linked answer, what should help you as well is changing your `add` to

```
def add(rdd:RDD[Int]) = {
  val localS = s
  rdd.map(e => e + " " + localS).foreach(println)
}
```

The main trick is introduction of the `localS` variable that forces `rddFunc` to capture just it rather than whole `B`.

***Sidenote***: In the code above I also changed signature of your `add` from

```
def add():Function1[RDD[Int], Unit]
```

that you had to

```
def add(rdd:RDD[Int]):Unit
```

There are no benefits in your case of `add` returning a function that you call immediately.

Comment: yes, but the problem is not due to differences between function and method. "localS" can work, while I'm still not clear why the whole object B will be serialized when "s" is captured.

Comment: @lzh, 1)Yes, that difference is not important to your question. It is just a little inefficiency. 2)I'm not sure what answer about `s` would satisfy you. This is just the way the Scala compiler works. The obvious benefit of this approach is simplicity: compiler doesn't have to analyze which fields and/or methods are used and which are not. If any is used - capture the whole `this` and use it to access everything. This is also more memory-efficient in most of the cases (you always capture one `this` instead of many fields). There is no hand-crafted optimization for your particular (rare) case.

Comment: SergGr, I have understood it this time, thanks for your detailed answer.