# Spark streaming nested execution serialization issues

Tags: database, apache-spark, serialization, streaming

I am trying to connect DB2 database in the spark streaming application and the database query execution statement causing "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable" issues. Please advise. Below is the sample code I have for reference.

```
        dataLines.foreachRDD{rdd=>
          val spark = SparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext.getConf)

          val dataRows=rdd.map(rs => rs.value).map(row =>
            row.split(",")(1)-> (row.split(",")(0), row.split(",")(1), row.split(",")(2)
              , "cvflds_"+row.split(",")(3).toLowerCase, row.split(",")(4), row.split(",")(5), row.split(",")(6))
          )

          val db2Conn = getDB2Connection(spark,db2ConParams)

          dataRows.foreach{ case (k,v) =>
              val table = v._4
              val dbQuery = s"(SELECT * FROM $table ) tblResult"
              val df=getTableData(db2Conn,dbQuery)
              df.show(2)
          }
        }


Below is other function code:

  private def getDB2Connection(spark: SparkSession, db2ConParams:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]): DataFrameReader = {
      spark.read.format("jdbc").options(db2ConParams)
  }

  private def getTableData(db2Con: DataFrameReader,tableName: String):DataFrame ={
      db2Con.option("dbtable",tableName).load()
  }



object SparkSessionSingleton {

  @transient  private var instance: SparkSession = _

  def getInstance(sparkConf: SparkConf): SparkSession = {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = SparkSession
        .builder
        .config(sparkConf)
        .getOrCreate()
    }
    instance
  }
}
```

Below is the error log:

2018-03-28 22:12:21,487 [JobScheduler]  ERROR org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler - Error running job streaming job 1522289540000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:915)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:915)
    at ncc.org.civil.receiver.DB2DataLoadToKudu$$anonfun$createSparkContext$1.apply(DB2DataLoadToKudu.scala:139)
    at ncc.org.civil.receiver.DB2DataLoadToKudu$$anonfun$createSparkContext$1.apply(DB2DataLoadToKudu.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader, value: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@15fdb01)
    - field (class: ncc.org.civil.receiver.DB2DataLoadToKudu$$anonfun$createSparkContext$1$$anonfun$apply$2, name: db2Conn$1, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader)
    - object (class ncc.org.civil.receiver.DB2DataLoadToKudu$$anonfun$createSparkContext$1$$anonfun$apply$2, )
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 30 more

Comment: Please post the full text of the error message, including stack trace.

Comment: Hi Ken, added the error log. Please check.

Comment: Can you just try with moving the spark session creation line out of dataLines.foreachRDD ?

Comment: Hey Vinod, moving spark session out of foreachRDD doesn't solve my problem. I have to query the database for each and every message I receive in the foreach loop.

Comment: Another guess is to make the methods as functions.Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should keep the closure in `dataRows.foreach` clear of any connection objects, since the closure is meant to be serialized to executors and run there. This concept is covered in depth @ this official [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)

In your case below line is the closure that is causing the issue:

`val df=getTableData(db2Conn,dbQuery)`

So, instead of using spark to get the DB2 table loaded, which in your case becomes(after combining the methods):

`spark.read.format("jdbc").options(db2ConParams).option("dbtable",tableName).load()`

Use plain JDBC in the closure to achieve this. You can use `db2ConParams` in the jdbc code. (I assume its simple enough to be serializable). The link also suggests using `rdd.foreachPartition` and `ConnectionPool` to further optimize.

You have not mentioned what you are doing with the table data except `df.show(2)`. If the rows are huge, then you may discuss more about your use case. Perhaps, you need to consider a different design then.

Comment: Sujit, thanks for your advice on using the traditional way of fetching the data. I tried on this it looks working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarutiK, glad to help. Consider upvoting/marking as answer.