# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Ran into this error when trying to run a spark streaming application with checkpointing enabled.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable
    Serialization stack:
    org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
    Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, value: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@63cf0da6)
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, value: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@63cf0da6)
        - field (class: com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream, name: streamingContext, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)
        - field (class: com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream, name: streamingContext, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)
        - object (class com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStreamFactory$$anon$1, com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStreamFactory$$anon$1@1738d3b2)
        - object (class com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStreamFactory$$anon$1, com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStreamFactory$$anon$1@1738d3b2)
        - field (class: com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream$$anonfun$runJob$1, name: $outer, type: class com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream)
        - field (class: com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream$$anonfun$runJob$1, name: $outer, type: class com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream)
        - object (class com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream$$anonfun$runJob$1, <function1>)
        - object (class com.sales.spark.job.streaming.SalesStream$$anonfun$runJob$1, <function1>)
```

Trying to execute the piece of code. I am thinking the issue has to do with trying to access the `spark` session variable inside the `tempTableView` function

**Code**

```
liveRecordStream
      .foreachRDD(newRDD => {
        if (!newRDD.isEmpty()) {
          val cacheRDD = newRDD.cache()
          val updTempTables = tempTableView(t2s, stgDFMap, cacheRDD)
          val rdd = updatestgDFMap(stgDFMap, cacheRDD)
          persistStgTable(stgDFMap)
          dfMap
            .filter(entry => updTempTables.contains(entry._2))
            .map(spark.sql)
            .foreach( df => writeToES(writer, df))
        }
      }
```

**tempTableView**

```
def tempTableView(t2s: Map[String, StructType], stgDFMap: Map[String, DataFrame], cacheRDD: RDD[cacheRDD]): Set[String] = {
    stgDFMap.keys.filter { table =>
      val tRDD = cacheRDD
        .filter(r => r.Name == table)
        .map(r => r.values)
         val tDF = spark.createDataFrame(tRDD, tableNameToSchema(table))
      if (!tRDD.isEmpty()) {
        val tName = s"temp_$table"
        tDF.createOrReplaceTempView(tName)
      }
      !tRDD.isEmpty()
    }.toSet
  }
```

Not sure how to get the spark session variable inside this function which is called inside `foreachRDD`.

I am instantiating the streamingContext as part of a different class.

```
class Test {
lazy val sparkSession: SparkSession =
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("testApp")
      .config("es.nodes", SalesConfig.elasticnode)
      .config("es.port", SalesConfig.elasticport)
      .config("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", parquetFilterPushDown)
      .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 100000)
      .config("spark.rdd.compress", rddCompress)
      .config("spark.task.maxFailures", 25)
      .config("spark.streaming.unpersist", streamingUnPersist)
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
lazy val streamingContext: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext,Seconds(15))
streamingContext.checkpoint("/Users/gswaminathan/Guidewire/Java/explore-policy/checkpoint/")
}
```

I tried extending this class as `Serializable`, but no luck.

Comment: Try `implicit lazy val streamingContext`

Comment: No luck. what does adding`implicit` do?

Comment: Marks it as something not to be serialized

Comment: I even tried @transient. Does not seem to work

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov would you be able to help here?

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)