# Iterate and trim string based on condition in spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe 'regexDf' like below

```
id,regex
1,(.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)text3(.*)text4(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)
2,(.*)text1(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)
```

If the length of the regex exceeds some max length for example 50, then i want to remove the last text token in splitted regex string separated by '|' for the exceeded id. In the above data frame, id 1 length is more than 50 so that last tokens 'text4(.*)' and 'text6(.*)' from each splitted regex string should be removed. Even after removing that also  length of the regex string in id 1 still more than 50, so that again last tokens 'text3(.*)' and 'text5(.*)' should be removed.so the final dataframe will be

```
id,regex
1,(.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)
2,(.*)text1(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)
```

I am able to trim the last tokens using the following code

```
  val reducedStr = regex.split("|").foldLeft(List[String]()) {
    (regexStr,eachRegex) => {
      regexStr :+ eachRegex.replaceAll("\\(\\.\\*\\)\\w+\\(\\.\\*\\)$", "\\(\\.\\*\\)")
    }
  }.mkString("|")
```

I tried using while loop to check the length and trim the text tokens in iteration which is not working. Also i want to avoid using var and while loop. Is it possible to achieve without while loop.

```
         val optimizeRegexString = udf((regex: String) => {
              if(regex.length >= 50) {
                var len = regex.length;
                var resultStr: String = ""
                while(len >= maxLength) {
                  val reducedStr = regex.split("|").foldLeft(List[String]()) {
                    (regexStr,eachRegex) => {
                      regexStr :+ eachRegex
    .replaceAll("\\(\\.\\*\\)\\w+\\(\\.\\*\\)$", "\\(\\.\\*\\)")
                    }
                  }.mkString("|")
                  len = reducedStr.length
                  resultStr = reducedStr
                }
                resultStr
              } else {
                regex
              }
            })
            regexDf.withColumn("optimizedRegex", optimizeRegexString(col("regex")))
```

As per SathiyanS and Pasha suggestion, I changed the recursive method as function.

```
      def optimizeRegex(regexDf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
        val shrinkString= (s: String) =>   {
          if (s.length > 50) {
            val extractedString: String = shrinkString(s.split("\\|")
.map(s => s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("text"))).mkString("|"))
            extractedString
          }
          else s
        }
        def shrinkUdf = udf((regex: String) => shrinkString(regex))
        regexDf.withColumn("regexString", shrinkUdf(col("regex")))
      }
```

Now i am getting exception as "recursive value shrinkString needs type"

```
    Error:(145, 39) recursive value shrinkString needs type
            val extractedString: String = shrinkString(s.split("\\|")
.map(s => s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("text"))).mkString("|"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion:

```
def shrink(s: String): String = {
if (s.length > 50)
  shrink(s.split("\\|").map(s => s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("text"))).mkString("|"))
else s
}
```

Looks like issues with function calling, some additional info.
Can be called as static function:

```
object ShrinkContainer  {
  def shrink(s: String): String = {
    if (s.length > 50)
      shrink(s.split("\\|").map(s => s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("text"))).mkString("|"))
    else s
  }
}
```

Link with dataframe:

```
def shrinkUdf = udf((regex: String) => ShrinkContainer.shrink(regex))
df.withColumn("regex", shrinkUdf(col("regex"))).show(truncate = false)
```

Drawbacks: Just basic example (approach) provided. Some edge cases (if regexp does not contains "text", if too many parts separated by "|", for ex. 100; etc.) have to be resolved by author of question, for avoid infinite recursion loop.

Comment: This worked. but i am not sure why making the function as object is giving me "recursive value needs type" error

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

First, a function for removing the last token from a regex:

```
def deleteLastToken(s: String): String =
  s.replaceFirst("""[^)]+\(\.\*\)$""", "")
```

Then, a function that shortens the entire regex string by deleting the last token from all the `|`-separated fields:

```
def shorten(r: String) = {
  val items = r.split("[|]").toSeq
  val shortenedItems = items.map(deleteLastToken)
  shortenedItems.mkString("|")
}
```

Then, for a given input regex string, create the stream of all the shortened strings you get by applying the `shorten` function repeatedly. This is an infinite stream, but it's lazily evaluated, so only as few elements as required will be actually computed:

```
val regex = "(.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)text3(.*)text4(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)"

val allShortened = Stream.iterate(regex)(shorten)
```

Finally, you can treat `allShortened` as any other sequence. For solving our problem, you can drop all elements while they don't satisfy the length requirement, and then keep only the first one of the remaining ones:

```
val result = allShortened.dropWhile(_.length > 50).head
```

You can see all the intermediate values by printing some elements of `allShortened`:

```
allShortened.take(10).foreach(println)

// Prints:
// (.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)text3(.*)text4(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)
// (.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)text3(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)text5(.*)
// (.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)
// (.*)text1(.*)|(.*)
// (.*)|(.*)
// (.*)|(.*)
// (.*)|(.*)
// (.*)|(.*)
// (.*)|(.*)
// (.*)|(.*)
```

Comment: This works in Scala. But didn't work in Spark. I want to make it work in spark.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @pasha701 answer. Here is the solution that works in spark.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"(.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)text3(.*)text4(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)"),(2,"(.*)text1(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)"))).toDF("ID", "regex")

df.show()
//prints
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID |regex                                                                   |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |(.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)text3(.*)text4(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)|
|2  |(.*)text1(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)                           |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now you can use the @pasha701 shrink function using udf

```
val shrink: String => String = (s: String) => if (s.length > 50) shrink(s.split("\\|").map(s => s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("text"))).mkString("|")) else s

def shrinkUdf = udf((regex: String) => shrink(regex))

df.withColumn("regex", shrinkUdf(col("regex"))).show(truncate = false)

//prints
+---+---------------------------------------------+
|ID |regex                                        |
+---+---------------------------------------------+
|1  |(.*)text1(.*)text2(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)         |
|2  |(.*)text1(.*)text5(.*)text6(.*)|(.*)text2(.*)|
+---+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I am getting "Task not serializable" error with the above logic.

Comment: Its working for me though. Are you running spark in local mode or cluster mode?

Comment: Spark is running in cluster mode

Comment: @Mohan methods are not serializable.. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou

Comment: After reading @SathiyanS post, I understood that in this case once should use functions and not methods. So I have edited the answer from using method to function. Let me know if you still face the issue.