# Parsing Data in Apache Spark Scala org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable error when trying to use textinputformat.record.delimiter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, hadoop2, spark-shell

Input file:

```
___DATE___

2018-11-16T06:3937
Linux hortonworks 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 30 05:26:04 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 06:39:37 up 100 days,  1:04, 2 users,  load average: 9.01, 8.30, 8.48
06:30:01 AM     all      6.08      0.00      2.83      0.04      0.00     91.06

___DATE___

2018-11-16T06:4037
Linux cloudera 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 30 05:26:04 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 06:40:37 up 100 days,  1:05, 28 users,  load average: 8.39, 8.26, 8.45
06:40:01 AM     all      6.92      1.11      1.88      0.04      0.00     90.05
```

Required output:

```
2018-11-16T06:3937,hortonworks, 2 users
2018-11-16T06:4037,cloudera, 28 users
```

I'm trying to get my hands on Spark with Scala. 
Trying to parse this input file with Spark 2.3.1 and scala 2.11.6 . Here's my code.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object parse_stats extends App {

  case class LoadSchema(date:String)

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ParseStats").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val hadoopConf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
  hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","___DATE___")

  val input = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("C:\\Users\\rohit\\Documents\\dataset\\sys_stats.log",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text],hadoopConf).map(line=>line._2.toString)

  lazy val date_pattern="[0-9]+[-][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[T][0-9]+[:][0-9]+".r
  lazy val uname_pattern="[Linux][0-9a-zA-z-#() . : _ /]+[GNU/Linux]".r
  lazy val cpu_regex="[ 0-9]+[:][0-9]+[:][0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z, : .]+[load average][:][0-9 . ,]+".r

  val transformRDD = input.map{eachline=>((if(date_pattern.pattern.matcher(eachline).matches()) eachline), //collects date
    (if(uname_pattern.pattern.matcher(eachline).matches()) eachline.split("\\s+")(1).trim() ), //collects hostname
    (if (cpu_regex.pattern.matcher(eachline).matches()) eachline.split(",")(2).trim()) //collects cpu users
  )
  }

  transformRDD.collect().foreach(println)
}
```

If run this code from Intellij, I get below output.

```
((),(),())
((),(),())
((),(),())
```

If I run from spark-shell, I get below error:

```
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

scala> import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

scala>   val hadoopConf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
hadoopConf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, __spark_hadoop_conf__.xml

scala>   hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","___DATE___")

scala>   val input = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("C:\\Users\\rnimmal1\\Documents\\dataset\\sys_stats.log",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text],hadoopConf).map(line=>line._2.toString)
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at <console>:37

scala>

scala>   lazy val date_pattern="[0-9]+[-][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[T][0-9]+[:][0-9]+".r
date_pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = <lazy>

scala>   lazy val uname_pattern="[Linux][0-9a-zA-z-#() . : _ /]+[GNU/Linux]".r
uname_pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = <lazy>

scala>   lazy val cpu_regex="[ 0-9]+[:][0-9]+[:][0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z, : .]+[load average][:][0-9 . ,]+".r
cpu_regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = <lazy>

scala>

scala>   val transformRDD = input.map{eachline=>((if(date_pattern.pattern.matcher(eachline).matches()) eachline), //collects date
     |     (if(uname_pattern.pattern.matcher(eachline).matches()) eachline.split("\\s+")(1).trim() ), //collects hostname
     |     (if (cpu_regex.pattern.matcher(eachline).matches()) eachline.split(",")(2).trim()) //collects cpu users
     |   )
     |   }
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:371)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:370)
  ... 54 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, value: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, __spark_hadoop_conf__.xml)
        - field (class: $iw, name: hadoopConf, type: class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@63fa0b9)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@3f4b52fa)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@338f9bb5)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@3d63becf)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@3aca7082)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@4ccfd904)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@6e4e7a62)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@5aaab2b0)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@5c51a7eb)
        - field (class: $line36.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $line36.$read, $line36.$read@2ba3b4a6)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $line36$read, type: class $line36.$read)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@6559f04e)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@8f7cbcc)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@465b16bb)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@373efaa2)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@5f2896fa)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@f777d41)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@43ec41d7)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@61c0a61)
        - field (class: $line38.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $line38.$read, $line38.$read@10d1f6da)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $line38$read, type: class $line38.$read)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@2095e085)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@380cb7e3)
        - field (class: $anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $anonfun$1, <function1>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:342)
  ... 63 more
```

What am I missing?

Comment: textinputformat.record.delimiter should be single character, not a word

Comment: As much as I know "textinputformat.record.delimiter" is not confined to single character.  
I used the same delimiter with Apache Pig and it worked there, and it should work in spark also, as this property is specific to hadoop.

Comment: it can be multibyte if the encoding is utf8 or utf16, but not a word.. I just ran and it ignores __DATA__  and takes the default newline. if you change __DATA__ to "|" the split happens

Comment: Thanks, I replaced DATE string with "|" in the data set and in the property as well, I see the code is working the same way. :(

Comment: Yes, that can also be done.. let me update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the `__DATA__` to pipe "|" , the below code snippet produces the required output. Note that I have used Windows platform, so I'm replacing "\r". Please check out

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark_test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val file1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("./in/machine_logs.txt")

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","|")

val file2 = file1.filter( line => { val x = line.split("""\n"""); x.length > 5 } )
                    .map( line => { val x = line.split("""\n""")
                      val p = x(2).replaceAll("\\r","") // not needed if Unix platform
                      val q = x(3).split(" ")(1)
                      val r = x(4).split(",")(2)
                      (p + "," + q + "," + r)
                    } )

file2.collect.foreach(println)
//file2.saveAsTextFile("./in/machine_logs.out") --> comment above line and uncomment this line to save in file
```

Output:

```
2018-11-16T06:3937,hortonworks, 2 users
2018-11-16T06:4037,cloudera, 28 users
```

**Update1:**

With regex matching:

```
val date_pattern="[0-9]+[-][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[T][0-9]+[:][0-9]+".r
val uname_pattern="(Linux) (.*?) [0-9a-zA-z-#() . : _ /]+(GNU/Linux)".r
val cpu_regex="""(.+),(.*?),\s+(load average)[:][0-9 . ,]+""".r
val file2 = file1.filter( line => { val x = line.split("""\n"""); x.length > 5 } )
  .map( line => {
          var q = ""; var r = "";
          val p = date_pattern.findFirstIn(line).mkString
          uname_pattern.findAllIn(line).matchData.foreach(m=> {q = m.group(2).mkString} )
          cpu_regex.findAllIn(line).matchData.foreach(m=> {r = m.group(2).mkString} )
          (p + "," + q + "," + r)
  } )
file2.collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try.

Comment: This worked! but I dont want to hardcode the line numbers (eg: x(2),x(3)). I want to get it working with pattern matching, I mean extract the value only if the string matches the pattern extract the data.

Comment: updated the answer. Note that I tweaked the regex that you used as there were some mistakes

Comment: Thanks mate! I figured it out just a while ago. Anyways thanks for your patience and help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are defining those filters objects (`date_pattern`) outside of the RDD, so Spark has to send the entire `parse_stats` object to all of the executors, which it cannot do because it cannot serialize that entire object. This doesn't happen when you run it in local mode because it doesn't need to send any objects to other executors.

Check out the great answer here: [Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)

This gist has some quick and simple ways to avoid serialization: https://gist.github.com/kmader/1d64e64621e63d566f67