# How to adjust function for Iterable Array?

Tags: arrays, scala, function, iterator, rdd

1974,1974-06-22
1966,1966-07-20
1954,1954-06-19
1994,1994-06-27
1954,1954-06-26
2006,2006-07-04
2010,2010-07-07
1990,1990-06-30
...

```
It is type RDD[String].

What is wrong in the function iteself?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
def f(v: Iterable[Array[String]]): Int = {
  val parsedDates = v.flatten.map(e => LocalDate.parse(e, formatter))
  parsedDates.max.getDayOfYear - parsedDates.min.getDayOfYear
}
```

which outputs

```
val arrays = Iterable(Array("2014-10-10","2014-12-10"))
f(arrays) // res0: Int = 61
```

Comment: Error:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou