# Task not serializable in community.cloud.databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Databricks community cloud is throwing 
 an `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` exception that my local machine is not throwing executing the same code.

The code comes from the Spark in Action book. What the code is doing is reading a json file with github activity data, then reading a file with employees usernames from an invented company, and ultimately ranks the employees by number of pushes.

To avoid extra shuffling, the variable containing the list of employees is broadcasted, however, when its time to return the rank, is when databricks community cloud throws the exception.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.io.Source.fromURL

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("GitHub push counter")
.master("local[*]")
.getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext

val inputPath = "/FileStore/tables/2015_03_01_0-a829c.json"
val pushes = spark.read.json(inputPath).filter("type = 'PushEvent'")
val grouped = pushes.groupBy("actor.login").count.orderBy(grouped("count").desc)

val empPath = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spark-in-action/first-edition/master/ch03/ghEmployees.txt"
val employees = Set() ++ (for { line <- fromURL(empPath).getLines} yield line.trim)

val bcEmployees = sc.broadcast(employees)

import spark.implicits._
val isEmp = user => bcEmployees.value.contains(user)
val isEmployee = spark.udf.register("SetContainsUdf", isEmp)
val filtered = ordered.filter(isEmployee($"login"))
filtered.show()
```

Comment: Is there no error outside of databricks?

Comment: I think not, hence you should change title and tags

Answer (score 1):

If you have custom classes like employee/user then you need to implement serialization interface.Spark when working with custom user objects,needs to serialize them.

[Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)